# Trouble starting multiprocess threads and using events

Tags: python, multithreading, events, multiprocess

I am trying to feed both an event and a queue to my worker threads. The queue is for them to talk to each other the event is for signalling them to stop working when needed. I keep getting this error and I cant quite figure out what is wrong with my definition constructors

Here is the error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "dualThreaded.py", line 52, in <module>
    c = get_Count(q, e)
 TypeError: __init__() takes exactly 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Here is my code:

```
 from Queue import Empty
 from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Event 
 import time

 class get_Count(object):
     def __init__(self, q): 
         self.q = q 

     def run(self, e):
         i = 0
     run = True
         while run == True:
             print 'putting' 
             self.q.put('foo %d' % i ) 
             time.sleep(.5)
          if e.is_set():
             run = False

class read_Count(object):
     def __init__(self, q):
         self.q = q 

     def run(self, e):
         while True:
             try:
                value =  self.q.get(False)
                print value

             except Empty:
                 print 'Nothing to process atm'
                 e.set()
             time.sleep(.2)



 if __name__ == '__main__':

     e = Event()
     q = Queue()
     c = get_Count(q, e)
     l = read_Count(q, e)

     p1 = Process(target=c.run)
     p1.start()

     p2 = Process(target=l.run)
     p2.start()

     p1.join()
     p2.join()
```

edit fixed typos:

Comment: Your code example doesn't correspond with the error message. There is no line 52, and there is no `get_Proc_Count` class. Also, the indenting is messed up. Please read the guidance on how to produce a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

Ignoring your inaccurate stack frame for a moment, consider `c = get_Count(q, e)`. `get_Count`'s initializer `def __init__(self, q):` only takes one parameter after the mandatory `self`, but you call it with two. I've updated your code to include `e` in your initializer and do some minor cleanup. it kinda runs but you will likely need to work out the next issue.

```
from Queue import Empty
from multiprocessing import Process, Queue, Event 
import time

class get_Count(object):
    def __init__(self, q, e): 
        self.q = q
        self.e = e

    def run(self):
        i = 0
        run = True
        while run == True:
            print 'putting' 
            self.q.put('foo %d' % i ) 
            time.sleep(.5)
            if self.e.is_set():
                run = False

class read_Count(object):
    def __init__(self, q, e):
        self.q = q
        self.e = e

    def run(self):
        while True:
            try:
                value =  self.q.get(False)
                print value

            except Empty:
                print 'Nothing to process atm'
                self.e.set()
            time.sleep(.2)


if __name__ == '__main__':

     e = Event()
     q = Queue()
     c = get_Count(q, e)
     l = read_Count(q, e)

     p1 = Process(target=c.run)
     p1.start()

     p2 = Process(target=l.run)
     p2.start()
```